Proof of Uniquness In Rocheteau and Wright (2005) competitive search model
In Rocheteau and Wright (2005), they compare three monetary models. I'm interested in the last one of them, the competitive search equilibrium model.
They study the equilibrium specifically when the number of sellers is fixed and when there is an entry at an exogenous cost $k$. I need to understand the one with entry.
Now, the uniqueness would imply only one submarket to open during the DM, but they say in the proof the following sentence:
" Finally, given that $\alpha(n)$ is in the compact set $[0,1]$ and strictly decreasing with $J$, there is at most a countable number of values for J such that $\tilde{N}(J)$ is not a singleton"
$n$ is the measure of sellers, $J$ is expected value of a seller during the DM, $\tilde{N}(J)$ is the convex hull of the set of solutions for $n$.
I don't understand this sentence. How does $\alpha(n)$ being in a compact set [0,1], while strictly decreasing in $J$ imply the rest of the proof sentence?
Thank you very much and I appreciate your help
